# Animated Screen Saver

Tags: c#, silverlight, screensaver

I have a requirement to create an animated screen saver for windows.
Screen saver contains some images and some text.
I want to update the screensaver contents from a a webpage (upload images and edit texts) etc.

is possible to do this using c#?

Answer (score 3):

"is possible to do this using c#?"

Yes.

C# is a full code language, and with it, you can do virtually everything a computer is able to do.
Now... I would expect you to expand your question a bit more.

Comment: Thak you for immediate responce, i need to create a screensaver for windows client.It contains some animations like sliding images and some text. Also i want to manage the screen saver from a remote server.Like if i upload a new image to server , all client machines download it and update the screen saver. this is my requirment.

Comment: Have you tried anything? We are not here to do the job for you, but to help you solve specific problems.